# How to restart sql server 2012 by using SQL

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to restart, start or stop sql server 2012 by executing SQL statement? thanks.

Comment: SQL statements run on the SQL Server. Suppose you have stopped it. Where must run your sql statement to start the server? So the answer is no.

Comment: But how to execute it from button which i place in winform application, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually **you can't do this from the SQL statement**, but you can perform this with the powershell/cmd

```
powershell -command "Restart-Service MSSQLSERVER -Force"
```

Answer (score 0):

[using the command line or powershell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403394.aspx).

`net start MSSQL$instancename`

`net stop MSSQL$instance`

using SSMS

`SHUTDOWN`  -->wait and shutdown

`SHUTDOWN WITH NOWAIT` --> dont wait and shutdown

Don't think there is a straight way you can startup in T-SQL, you probably have to do something [like this.](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/t-sql-add-sql-server-startup-parameters)

Comment: I know this how to do on command line or powershell. But i want to execute it from button and for this i need to execute it by using SQL, thanks.

Comment: Now iam having problem in running this command on both command line and powershell. Iam using sql server 2012 express edition. How can i replace your above command to run sql server express.

Comment: @user3004110 look at the bottom examples I listed. It's how to shut down, and startup using purely SQL. Click on the link to look at the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xp_cmdshell` system procedure to call any command line to stop; however, you definitely can't start it because how will you execute a command using T-SQL while you are not connected (service is stopped)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly start or stop SQL Server itself using SQL statements, you can perform tasks related to database management, such as starting, stopping, and restarting individual databases within SQL Server using SQL statements.